# Convert 1-to-n XML column to tabular data

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table on MS SQL server that holds information about reports in XML format. The table consists of two fields: the first has the business key, the second the entire report in XML format.

These reports include several pictures each. The XML holds information about these pictures, such as their filename, taken date, etc. I want to extract this information into a table, where every record holds information about exactly one photo. I've found ways to do this that come very close, but the problem I keep running into is that I need to create several records in this table for every record in my source table. How can I make this work?

The business key needs to be in the final table as well. This business key can be found in the XML data, but there is also a separate field in the source table (as mentioned before) where it can be found. The content of the XML column could look similar to this:

```
<Report>
  <ReportKey>0000001</ReportKey>
  [...]
  <Photos>
    <Photo>
      <Filename>1.jpg</Filename>
      <Date>01-01-2015</Date>
    </Photo>
    <Photo>
      <Filename>2.jpg</Filename>
      <Date>01-01-2016</Date>
    </Photo>
    [...]
  </Photos>
  [...]
</Report>
```

I want the final table to look like this:

```
+---------+----------+------------+
|   Key   | Filename |    Date    |
+---------+----------+------------+
| 0000001 | 1.jpg    | 01-01-2015 |
| 0000001 | 2.jpg    | 01-01-2016 |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

Comment: I've been able to make it work today, thanks to your last solution. I'll make sure to upvote it and mark the question as solved. Thanks for your help, you've been great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comments the OP needs an approach to get this from table row data and the existing answer is not solution enough.

You might try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable(BusinessKey VARCHAR(10),ReportData XML);
INSERT INTO #YourTable VALUES
 ('0000001','<Report>
              <ReportKey>0000001</ReportKey>
              <Photos>
                <Photo>
                  <Filename>1.jpg</Filename>
                  <Date>2015-01-01</Date>
                </Photo>
                <Photo>
                  <Filename>2.jpg</Filename>
                  <Date>2016-05-13</Date>
                </Photo>
              </Photos>
            </Report>')
,('0000002','<Report>
              <ReportKey>0000002</ReportKey>
              <Photos>
                <Photo>
                  <Filename>3.jpg</Filename>
                  <Date>2015-04-19</Date>
                </Photo>
                <Photo>
                  <Filename>4.jpg</Filename>
                  <Date>2016-12-10</Date>
                </Photo>
              </Photos>
            </Report>');

SELECT BusinessKey AS Table_Key 
      ,ReportData.value('(/Report/ReportKey)[1]','varchar(10)') AS XML_Key
      ,Photo.value('Filename[1]','varchar(max)') AS Photo_Filename
      ,Photo.value('Date[1]','date') AS Photo_Date
FROM #YourTable
CROSS APPLY ReportData.nodes('/Report/Photos/Photo') AS A(Photo);
GO

DROP TABLE #YourTable;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is **not** an answer, but important enough not to end up in a comment:

Be very careful with date formats. I do not know how your XML is generated, but the date *within* an XML should be ISO 8601 (`yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`).

Your format is **culture dependant !!!**

Try this:

```
set language french;
declare @xml as xml ='<x><Date>08-03-2015</Date></x>';
select @xml.value('(/x/Date)[1]','datetime');

set language english;
select @xml.value('(/x/Date)[1]','datetime');
```

You see, that the results differ?

Now try to set the date to the 13th of March. There's even a conversion exception!

Comment: I've checked with the XML files, and they're in the ISO format you mention. I made up the example code without regard for the date format. Nevertheless thanks for your response, I knew that date formatting was important but not all the details you gave me!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood the question. However, try this.

```
create table t (
    [Key]      int,
    [Filename] nvarchar(max),
    [Date]     date
)
```

```
declare @xml as xml = '<Report>
  <ReportKey>0000001</ReportKey>
  <Photos>
    <Photo>
      <Filename>1.jpg</Filename>
      <Date>01-01-2015</Date>
    </Photo>
    <Photo>
      <Filename>2.jpg</Filename>
      <Date>01-01-2016</Date>
    </Photo>
  </Photos>
</Report>'

insert into t ([Key], [Filename], [Date])
select n.value('ReportKey[1]', 'int')
     , x.value('Filename[1]',  'nvarchar(max)')
     , x.value('Date[1]',      'date')   
from @xml.nodes('Report') as r(n)
cross apply r.n.nodes('Photos/Photo') as t(x)

select * from t
```

Comment: Great answer, +1 from my side. Some tiny hints: You don't need the `./`, just `.value('ReportKey[1]','int')` is sufficient, and - if I understand this correctly - there is a table with many records and no need to store the result in a persistant table. Maybe you want to reflect this in your answer...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'd already tried this type of solution (I should have specified that, in hindsight). The problem lies in the fact that I want the code to run over the entire source table, and for every record in that source table, create several records in my query result. The code you've written here would run only over one XML file, not several. Some solutions I've considered are concatenating all xml files (though that would mean a massive performance loss), or setting the @xml variable from a query result. I'm not quite sure how to do that, though.